# Creating child-theme from other template files

Tags: child-theme

I’ve created the child-theme of [Kiyoshi theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/kiyoshi/) with the `style.css` file and `functions.php`, but now I want to modify the structure files which are put in inc/structure – how can I do this?

Copying the inc/structure folders and modifying the files didn’t work. Putting them outside any folders absolutely destroyed the whole theme (if You change and put `footer.php` in the same hierarchy as `style.css` for example, it just disappears from the web). Should I use some function in those files so WordPress will load them instead of the main files? The author of the theme didn't respond for over a month.

Here's how it looks: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific theme this question cannot be answered without analyzing all template files. More in general, a theme structured like this is almost impossible to make a child theme for.

Take `footer.php`. If you just put that in your child theme it will be called at the appropriate moment. But if that file tries to call templates from the inc-folder and you haven't moved those as well, nothing might be displayed.

The other way around, if the thing you want to change is in one of those inc-files, you can put it in the right folder in your child theme, but it won't be called if `footer-php` is still in the parent directory, from where it will call the parent inc-file.

To complicate things even further, any inc-file may be called from several parent templates. So to change a single thing in one inc-file, you would have to move several parent templates and, as a consequence, all the other inc-files that are called from the parent templates.

Anyway, you may end up copying the complete parent theme to the child folders to keep things working and you might as well change the parent theme itself.

Comment: First of all, thank You for Your answer @cjbj. As I thought, it's more complicated to work on this theme than on the others. I like it though (theme, not the fact that it has complicated structure) so I'll give it a try. I didn't want to build one myself because of the time needed to do that. But You gave me a hint - what if I copy whole theme to the child-folder and then try to modify inc/structure files? Will let You know if that works!

Comment: Good luck trying that. Meanwhile you could perhaps +1 or accept this answer, so the system takes it off the "unanswered" list.

Comment: I'd love to do that but the system won't let me - even being on stack for a few months :/ I find the rules of the Stack stupid 'cause I don't have time to play in the "if I do that, they let me participate in the forum" game.